# Rails 3 before_filter setting and checking boolean values | paperchase / treasure hunt game

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, qr-code, before-filter

I am working on a paperchase / treasure hunt mobile web app. I have basic authentication, if the user scans any of the following codes he will be directed to the sign_up page. So far everything works fine but here comes the tricky part:

I have 10 QR-Codes, every single one represents one URL.

1. QR-Code ID:1 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/4975
2. QR-Code ID:2 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/2368
3. QR-Code ID:3 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/2317
4. QR-Code ID:4 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/2369
5. QR-Code ID:5 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/6247
6. QR-Code ID:6 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/1493
7. QR-Code ID:7 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/1759
8. QR-Code ID:8 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/4278
9. QR-Code ID:9 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/8912
10. QR-Code ID:10 URL:http://paperchase.heroku.com/qrs/5346

Now I want the user to scan every single code in the shown order. If he scans Code 1, he will find the directions to Code 2, if he scans Code 2, he will find the directions to Code 3 and so on. But right now it is possible to skip codes, e.g. you could scan code 10 after code 1 and win.

**The solution I came up with:**

All QR-Codes are set to false. If you scan QR-Code 1, it will be set to true and you can scan QR-Code 2. If you now want to scan QR-Code 5, it redirects you to the root_path because QR-Code 4 is set to false.

This is part of my User model:

```
  ...
  t.boolean :qr_01, :default => false
  t.boolean :qr_02, :default => false
  t.boolean :qr_03, :default => false
  t.boolean :qr_04, :default => false
  ...
```

Now I think that I have to write some kind of `before_filter` with the logic (setting QR-Codes to true, checking if all the prior QR-Codes are set to true) But I have no clue how it should look like.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just store one int field in your model?

For example if my User model had

```
 t.integer :qr_code
```

You could simply check inside your controller action:

```
def add_qr
  user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if user.qr_code != params[:qr_code]-1
    redirect_to(some_url)
  else
    user.qr_code+=1
    user.save
    #do whatever else you need to do and display view
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to put your validation in the wrong place and your schema could use a bit of adjustment.

If someone is inputing QR4, do you really care that they've input QR1 through QR3 already or do you really only care that the last one they input was QR3? At the moment that the new code is being entered, what really matters is that it follows immediately after the last one; and, to make things consistent, you could have a virtual QR0 to represent the "none have been entered yet" state.

In your user model, you'd have a method like this:

```
def add_code(qr)
    # Check that qr immediately follows self.last_qr;
    # if it does, then update and save things and
    # continue on; if it doesn't, then raise an
    # exception that says, more or less, "QR Code out
    # of sequence".
end
```

You could track the last and current codes in your user model and use a validation hook to make sure they're okay:

```
before_create :initialize_qrs
validate :contiguous_qrs

#...

def initialize_qrs
  self.last_qr   = 0
  self.latest_qr = 0
end

def contiguous_qrs
  if(self.last_qr == 0 && self.latest_qr == 0)
    # New user, no worries.
    true
  elsif(self.latest_qr != self.last_qr + 1)
    # Sequence error, your `add_code` method should
    # prevent this from ever happening but, hey, bugs
    # happen and your code shouldn't trust itself any
    # more than it has to.
    false
  end
  true
end
```

Your `add_code` method would do set `self.last_qr` and `self.latest_qr` while it was doing its other work.

Then, over in your controller:

```
def enter_code
    # Get the code and validate it, leave it in qr
    begin
      current_user.add_code(qr)
    rescue Exception => e
      # Complain and wag your finger at them for cheating
    end
    # Give them instructions for finding the next one,
    # these instructions would, presumably, come from
    # something like "instructions = qr.next_one.instructions".
end
```

Tracking the (user,QR-Code) pairs makes sense for auditing purposes but it would make more sense to me to have a separate model (as an association table) for that:

```
create table "user_qr_codes" do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.integer  "user_id",    :null => false
  t.integer  "qr_code_id", :null => false
end
```

And then link that association up with your User and QrCode models in the usual manner.

Also note that this structure would only need a couple of simple modifications to allow for multiple "paper chases" to be running at the same time. You'd just need to move a couple things from your user model to a `user_paper_chases` model and add a `paper_chase` parameter to `User#add_code`.

There's no rule that says that your user interface has to be a simple editor for your data model properties and tightly binding the two like that is often a mistake (an incredibly common mistake but a mistake nonetheless).

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer. For now I got everything running with @Msencenb's idea. I will dig into your approach an try to improve my code asap.